# Multiple account's linked to one (Admin) Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create "child" accounts for a registered user.

So, after signing up and authenticating the account I would like to give that user the possibility to register further accounts; for other people to use without the need of an additional email or authentication. These child accounts would be linked back to the main user and that main user can delete/update them.

I am not sure if this is possible with Firebase. I have done some research but have not found a simple or any solution.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can do that but there are caveats.

The biggest one is an admin/user situation is that when .createUser is called from the admin account (on the device) it will automatically log IN the createdUser and log OUT the admin. There are a number of posts regarding this behavior.

There are a number of options but one that I would suggest is to leverage the Firebase [Admin Auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) which allows you to manage users without having to continually utilize the Firebase Console or do one of the workarounds required on the client side. A node.js example of creating a user looks like this

```
admin
  .auth()
  .createUser({
    email: 'user@example.com',
    emailVerified: false,
    phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
    password: 'secretPassword',
    displayName: 'John Doe',
    photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled: false,
  })
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
  });
```

Comment: Fantastic Jay, thank you for the answer I shall look into it! If you know of any other useful posts I'd really appreciate it!